# How to design a system in Google Sheets that allows for people who don't speak the same language to know they're typing the same thing

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, translation

I admit this is a strange request. Essentially myself and another person who speaks Mandarin need to work on scheduling asynchronously through a spreadsheet. If either of us enters something in, in our respective sections, it should update the other person's section to match. So If I changed Order 1 on Day 1 from Apple to Butter, it should look at the translated text for Butter in Chinese and update the dropdown list entry for Order 1 on Day 1 from Apple to Butter

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there's anyway to add formulas to dropdown lists. Any advice here?

I created a super simplified spreadsheet of what I'm looking for [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEFIB8PRA3kMUBNtr7BO6uqYlH69tawj8iCpquNlHD0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

there is a `GOOGLETRANSLATE` formula:

[image]

also, you have `DETECTLANGUAGE` that outputs the language code:

[image]

both of them (`DETECTLANGUAGE` is able to work with vertical arrays only) are not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA` so you will need to drag them around. also, it's worth mentioning that formulae are always 1-directional so you can have a dropdown to be translated but that translated output can't be used directly as the input for back-translation creating a paradox. with a scripted solution, you may have more flexibility tho.